# I am using a free autocomplete feature but not able to increase the size of the selectbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using a free autocomplete feature -
http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

but not able to increase the size of the select box. if I add these lines to the page

```
.ui-widget .ui-widget {
font-size: 12px;
width: 100%;
```

}

then the width increases but the down arrow and x stay in the middle of the combo box

Comment: I don't think listing the same class twice is what you want. Have you tried `.ui-widget input`?

Comment: The size of the menu that you're trying to edit is controlled by javascript. When the menu is displayed it is always set to the size of the input control. So if you want to change the size of the drop down menu then change the size of the form control.

Answer (score -1):

As @brassxzero menitoned, you need to style the `input` element.

```
#tags {
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 75%;
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/kkxwzrh4/

Comment: yes, tried all options.

<div class="ui-widget">
                <select id="cbotest" runat="server" style="width: 100%;"></select>

            </div>

Comment: @user4946275 Did you review the jsfiddle? Did I misunderstand your post?

Comment: Hi,

yes, reviewed the jsfiddle and worked the same way but I get the message that object doesn't support property or method autocomplete

I have added the following as well - 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: Is this in the fiddle or your own script?

Comment: Hi @Twisty, I got that part to work, there was a typo in my code but how do I change the source: availableTags to the values from my database?

Comment: There is a demo for that. Give it a stab and post another question if needed. If this answer has addressed this past, I hope you'll mark it as the answer.